# Where am I going wrong in getting an integral without anything to integrate with respect to?

Tags: integration

I want to evaluate the integral

$\int I(\vec{dl}\times\vec{B}).$

I have that $\vec{dl}=b\sin{\theta}\hat{z}+a\cos{\theta}\hat{y}.$

Thus

$\vec{dl}\times\vec{B}=-bB\sin{\theta}\hat{x}$,

so

$\int{I(\vec{dl}\times\vec{B})}=-\int{IbB\sin{\theta}\hat{x}}.$

However, I am now in a situation where there is nothing to integrate with respect to. What could be the problem?

Comment: It seems it should be $\vec{dl}=b\sin{\theta}\hat{z}dz+a\cos{\theta}\hat{y}dy.$

Comment: Yes, the RHS of $dl$ should be differential too.

Comment: Oh yes of course, thanks.